# JQuery conditional preventDefault() firing when not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, preventdefault

I have the following script I've written.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('a').data('loop',true);
      $('body').on('click', 'a', function(event){
        console.log($(this).data('loop'));
        if ($(this).data('loop') == 'true') {
          console.log('hit');
          event.preventDefault();
          caller = $(this);
          $(this).data('loop',false);
          var linkref = $(this).attr('href');
          var linkpos = $(this).offset();
          var screenwidth = $(window).width();
          var json_data = JSON.stringify({linkref: linkref, linkpos: linkpos, screenwidth: screenwidth});
          $.ajax({
            url: "content/submitcontenthandler?handler=core/_dashboard&method=tracking_ping",
            method: "POST",
            data: "json=" + json_data,
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
              console.log(status);
              console.log(caller);
              $(caller).click();
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.log(event.isDefaultPrevented());
          console.log('miss');
          $(this).data('loop',true);
        } 
      });
    });
  </script>
```

It works, sends me the details I want etc etc.  BUT!!!

When I click a link, It fires off the details to me via Ajax, then it's meant to "click" the event again, which it does!  but the event does not fire it's normal action.  So When clicking a link to another page, I would go to that other page... that's not happening.

If I comment out the line event.preventDefault();  Then the event fires as I would expect...

So to me it looks like the event.preventDefault is executing even though it's not meant to be during the second call...

Sorry if this is a bit complicated to understand. I don't quite understand what's happening myself.
Is it possibly a bug, or is there something that I've done that has caused this?

I didn't think I could, but I have successfully made a jsfiddle for this.
https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/2001/

Comment: Looks like the value you're assigning to `caller` is incorrect, it should be `$(this)` not `this`.

Comment: @KallumTanton Thanks, I've done that update.  It still functions the same, (though I can see the difference between what's now an object, and what was previously a string)  However it's still not sending me to my destination when I click a link...

Comment: I think you should put the first statement in the "ready" function

Comment: `$(caller).click()` will not redirect to the anchor target if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @apokryfos  Awesome!  :)  That's good to know.  How would I redirect to the link, short of $(location).attr("href", $(this).attr('href'));

Comment: @TolMera You want to redirect user to link clicked href after saving click data on server through ajax right?

Comment: Yes absolutly correct.  I do plan to extend this to include other things as well, such as forms (that might process sepperatly over ajax and not trigger a page load), or someone clicking/dragging a map et al...  Greater scope than this question covers, but hopefully I don't have too much trouble figguring that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this and not worry about the "loop" anymore:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var caller = $(this);
        var linkref = $(this).attr('href');
        var linkpos = $(this).offset();
        var screenwidth = $(window).width();
        var json_data = JSON.stringify({linkref: linkref, linkpos: linkpos, screenwidth: screenwidth});
        $.ajax({
            url: "content/submitcontenthandler?handler=core/_dashboard&method=tracking_ping",
            method: "POST",
            data: "json=" + json_data,
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(caller);
                window.location.href = linkref; // Redirect happens here
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

There's a few issues to note here:

1) Some links don't require a redirect (as noted, bootstrap model links that control showing/hiding or within document anchors

To correct this it really depends on the case. Usually bootstrap adds specific classes or data attributes to the links so you can do something like.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a:not(list of things to exclude)'..
```

Personally I'd instead define the links I wanted to track as :

```
<a href=<link> data-tracked='true'...

<script> 
      $('body').on("click","a[data-tracked='true']"...
```

Or if you want to track most links with a few exceptions you can:

```
     <a href=<link> data-tracked='false'...
     <script> 
          $('body').on("click","a:not([data-tracked='false'])"...
```

Or more generally:

```
 <script> 
      $('body').on("click","a", function () {
            if ($(this).attr("data-tracked") == "false" || <you can check more things here>){ 
                  return true; //Click passes through
             } 
             //Rest of the tracking code here
      });
```

Comment: What is user clicks on two links one after one and ajax response for first didn't complete yet; then what will happen?

Comment: Thanks! Pretty straight forward...
I wonder about one thing though, if the user hits a link that doesn't go anywhere.  like for Bootstrap models, or anchor tags being used to show/hide content, or actually being used as anchors in the page.  would this cause the page to reload every time?

Comment: If the user clicks a link, then another, and second Ajax does not complete, I don't really mind.  I'm just using this to track where the user is clicking, I might loose a little data here and there, but it should be a low fraction over the whole.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I'd expect the redirect to happen to whichever AJAX request finished first. This doesn't necessarily mean it would be the first link clicked though.

Comment: @TolMera you have a point with links that don't redirect anywhere I'll update the response. Now about the multiple clicks in quick succession part, I don't have a clue on how to get around it easily.

Comment: @apokryfos @TolMera For this we can temporary block browser till the ajax don't complete using `async: false` and we can also add class to `a` elements we don't want to redirect anywhere and check for this class existence in the `complete` callback;

Comment: I'm not sure if this is heading into discussion teritory, so hopefully the powers that be don't mind the multiple comments :).  The Ajax calls are taking 70~100ms on my browser, so blocking the browser for that amount of time would be ok. (noone likes when their browser becomes unresponsive, and I don't want to be intrusive).  Adding a class would be harder than checking if attr('href') exists, and skipping the redirect if it didn't exist.  So that might be better.

Comment: See updated response: Personally I'd add a data-attribute to include / exclude links that I want tracked/not tracked (depending on what's easier to check). Blocking the browser is also an option (if the response time is less than 70ms no one will notice that anyway because 70ms is the human response time to visual stimuli).

Comment: Sir you are a Scholar and a Gent!

A few quick notes for anyone else coming across this Q/A.  This works for getting links to run 'correctly'.  Anchor links will work as well, but they will cause a page reload.  (minor if you have precache, and browser cache).  This should also cause Modles to work, since they fire by (fragment) subref (URI#subref)  But again, you will get a page reload.  Anything not URI based, or subref'ed will probably not work nicely.  So as apokryfos noted, use data-attr inc/excl to pass those. You should be able to 'nest' the function to deal with edge cases. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The following if statement will return true whenever the `data-loop` attribute exists against an element, regardless of it's value:

```
if ($(this).data('loop')) {
```

It needs to be changed to check for the value:

```
if ($(this).data('loop') == 'true') {
```

When you assign anything to be the value of an element attribute it becomes a string and, as such, requires a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`Event.preventDefault()` is not being executed second time.

Link redirection happens when the method is completed. 
So in your case redirection will happen when `complete` method of ajax call  is completed.

lets say, we have event1 and event2 object in the code. event1 is the object in the ajax call method and event2 is the event object in recursive call (second call) method.

so when link is clicked second time , we still have `complete` method to be executed. as soon as it returns to the `complete` method of ajax call, it finds the event1 is having `preventDefault property true` and it does not redirect.

Comment: Ok That's a little bit difficult to understand, but I think I get the idea.  If you could explain a little more that would be great!  Or do you perhaps have an idea how I could make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var caller = $(this);
    var linkref = $(this).attr('href');
    var linkpos = $(this).offset();
    var screenwidth = $(window).width();

    var json_data = JSON.stringify({
      linkref: linkref,
      linkpos: linkpos,
      screenwidth: screenwidth
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: "content/submitcontenthandler?handler=core/_dashboard&method=tracking_ping",
      method: "POST",
      /* To temprary block browser; */
      async: false,
      data: "json=" + json_data,
      complete: function(jqXHR, status){
        /* add class **ignore** to a element you don't want to redirect anywhere(tabs, modals, dropdowns, etc); */
        if(!caller.hasClass('ignore')){
          /* Redirect happens here */
          window.location.href = linkref;
        }
      }
    });

  });
});
```